# "It was made beautiful" and "It was made beautifully"

Tags: adjectives, adverbs

- It was made beautiful
- It was made beautifully
- I'm hurt badly
- I'm hurt bad

Which one is correct? Since I know that in the active voice, we can use both with different meanings. Does the passive voice apply the same rule?

Comment: The first is correct.  The second is not.  Note that the two parts of the first have different meanings.

Comment: What is the difference in meaning between *I'm hurt badly* and *I'm hurt bad*?

Comment: it depends entirely on the context.  all could be right or wrong, depending on what preceeded.

Answer (score 9):

'It was made beautiful' means that something was not beautiful at first but you did things to it to cause it to be beautiful. Here 'beautiful' is an adjective.

'It was made beautifully' means that something was produced in a beautiful manner. Here 'beautifully' is an adverb.

'I am hurt badly' means that you are injured in a bad way, with 'badly' used as an adverb, while 'I am hurt [bad](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/bad)' is not used in ordinary circumstances but may be used informally in American English to mean 'I am hurt badly', with 'bad' replacing 'badly' as the adverb.

Note that 'bad' is usually used as an adjective, as in 'Will is a bad boy'.

Comment: I like the answer except for your discussion of *bad*. Although colloquial, I feel it is an adjective for the same reasons you describe for."beautiful* such as *I am __bad__.*

Comment: @StuW: It seems to me to be an adverb. As Will says, it is modifying the meaning of the verb phrase "am hurt", not of the noun phrase "I".